# php? Get random line from .txt file, make it static to create url's on a page

Tags: php

I don't know a thing about coding and this is the first thing that I managed to run.

Here it goes.

I found this code

```
<?php
$lines = file('my_file.txt');
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
?>
```

It takes a random line from my_file.txt and displays it.

I want to create a simple .php page, that would take a random line(or maybe take it one by one?) from my_file.txt and pass it to the end of my hyperlink like `http://www.google.com/(random_line_from_my_file.txt)`

For example:
`my_file.txt` contains 3 lines:

```
a
b
c
```

I want my .php page should show `http://www.google.com/a` or `http://www.google.com/b` or `http://www.google.com/c`.

Is it possible to make this work?

One more thing, is it possible to make that the chosen random line stays static on the whole page, until we refresh the page?

For example: If i wanted to have 3 hyperlinks on my simple .php page, so that it would always show :

```
http://www.google.com/a
http://www.bing.com/a
http://www.yahoo.com/a
```

instead of something random like

```
http://www.google.com/a
http://www.bing.com/b
http://www.yahoo.com/b
```

Comment: Youd probably be better off storing these options in a variable as opposed to a file but they would work the same just one way has a bit less code.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
<?php
    $lines = file ('file.txt', 
        FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $line = $lines [array_rand ($lines, 1)]; 
    foreach (array ("google", "bing", "yahoo") as $d) {
        $u = "www.$d.com/" . $line;
        echo "<a href=\"http://$u\">$u</a><br/>\n";
    }
?>
```